# Push notifications for 500k user's. ActiveMQ supports it?

Tags: android, push-notification, activemq-classic

I want to be able to push a single notification from my website to a client's Android.

The target is about 500k registered users.

Will ActiveMQ support this? Are there other choices? What architecture should I follow?

Answer (score 1):

I think your best aim for this would be a message- or worker queue. A very popular worker system is Gearman (http://www.gearman.org/).

If you want to take a simpeler approach, I suggest Beanstalk, in combination with Pheanstalk API (if you use PHP for your application development). See http://kr.github.io/beanstalkd/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You're better off with Google's [GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html).

You can send 1,000,000 messages in about 2 seconds with it ([source](http://developer.android.com/training/cloudsync/gcm.html)).

Comment: I don't want to depend on Google Services. My target is also smartphones with no Google Services installed. Perhaps I am reinventing the wheel, but in that case I learn in the process.